# How to give opening and closing time for contract in remix

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, crowdsale, timestamp

I have implemented a timed crowdsale contract and it's constructor is like this:

```
function NeoCrowdsale(uint256 _openingTime, uint256 _closingTime) public {
    require(_openingTime >= now);
    require(_closingTime >= _openingTime);

    openingTime = _openingTime;
    closingTime = _closingTime;
}
```

I need to deploy it to ropsten using remix, while creating it, I have to pass the opening and closing time, this is the screenshot where I need to specify it:

[image]

I'm just wondering the format to enter time in it along date, can anyone help me with this? If I want to deploy it on ***31 march 2018 at 10:00 am***

Thanks, any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the right times, you need to know what `now` or `blockstamp.timestamp` represents. This is UNIX time.

To quickly find this, use https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

To confirm this is right, create a function which returns the current timestamp. Now in your browser, enter `Date.now()/1000` (`Date.now()` returns microseconds) in your console. This is the current UNIX timestamp (and has nothing to do with your timezone), confirming that it is a UNIX timestmap.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to  https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ as mentioned by @MathematicalRain to see the Timestamp converter.
2. Enter the time and date you want then click convert it to change it to Unix Time Stamp (in seconds).
3. go to Remix and put the seconds there.